# Building regular expression ending with either one word or other

Tags: regex

I would like some help in building a regular expression. The conditions are as follows

- The expression must start with `#`
- Then it should contain atleast one or more groups of alphanumeric characters separated by `-`
- Each group contains atleast **one** alphanumeric character
- The expression should end either with `-apples` or `-bananas`

**Some test cases**

1. #hshg1h2-hd212df-7632jhsd-bananas         (Match)
2. #jhkj31j-jkh213j-jjkhjj324-apples         (Match)
3. hjsdjjhsd-jhsshdjs-jdshdsj-apples         (No Match)
4. #---apples                                (No Match)
5. #jhkj31j-jkh213j-jjkhjj324                (No Match)
6. #jhkj31j-jkh213j-jjkhjj324-apples-bananas (No Match)

I created the following expression
`^#([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}-){1,}(apples|bananas)$`. For most of the test cases, it provides the correct result. However it also matches the test case **6** which it should not.

**Background**

The test cases simulate product-ids for the two products apples and
bananas. Those ids always contains as the last group `-bananas` or `-apples`. Thus `-apples-bananas` or vice versa is suppose be invalid product id.

Could anyone please show me how can I do this?

Comment: FYI, `{1,}` is usually written as `+`.

Comment: Why isn't that correct? `bananas` is a group of alphanumeric characters, so it's allowed before the last word.

Comment: You could explicitly only match groups that do not contain apples or bananas before you reach the last group. Something like this, using a lookahead: `^#(?:(?!apples|bananas)[a-zA-Z0-9]+-)+?(?:apples|bananas)$`.

Comment: @oriberu: if you don't add word boundaries, the pattern will fail with "#appleseed-apples". `(?!apples\b|bananas\b)`. Also the non-greedy quantifier makes the pattern less efficient, change it to a greedy one.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Thanks for the note on word bounderies; you're right. I would only change to a greedy quantifier for the groups in the beginning, if I expected more than the ones given in the examples. With fewer groups in front, avoiding backtracking from the last group will probably be slightly more efficient.

Comment: @oriberu I tried your solution and it works as expected. Thank you for your help. If you answer this question with your solution, i will accept it. Could you also explain in the answer a little bit how this works and how did come to the idea of look ahead. I struggle with lookahead and back tracking. This will help me learn about it and hopefully others too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lookaheads and alteration:

```
/^#(?!.*apples.*bananas|.*bananas.*apples)(?=[a-zA-Z0-9]+-[a-zA-Z0-9]+).*(?:apples|bananas)$/
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7WD33V/1)

And it is always good to use word boundary assertions:

```
/^#(?!.*\bapples\b.*\bbananas\b|.*\bbananas\b.*\bapples\b)(?=[a-zA-Z0-9]+-[a-zA-Z0-9]+).*(?:\bapples\b|\bbananas\b)$/
```

Alternatively, here is a modified version of the regex in comments (that is pretty good!)

```
^#(?:(?!\b(?:apples|bananas)\b)[a-zA-Z0-9]+-)+\b(?:apples|bananas)$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7WD33V/2)